# Finite generation of equivariant cohomology rings

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a topological space $X$. (In my applications, $X$ is the classifying space of a compact Lie group.) Let $H^\ast(-)=H^\ast(-;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ denote mod 2 singular cohomology.

By the work of Quillen ("The Spectrum of an Equivariant Cohomology Ring: I"), if $H^\ast(X)$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-module, then the equivariant cohomology
$$H^\ast_G(X) = H^\ast(EG\times_G X)$$
is a finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.

My question is, if we only assume that $H^\ast(X)$ is finitely generated *as an algebra*, does the conclusion still hold, ie is the equivariant cohomology $H^\ast_G(X)$ necessarily finitely generated as an algebra?

**More background**

The standard tool for computing equivariant cohomology is the Leray-Serre spectral sequence of the fibration $X\to EG\times_G X \to BG$, which has
$$H^\ast(BG,H^\ast(X)) \Longrightarrow H^\ast(EG\times_G X)$$
*as algebras*.

Now if $G$ acts trivially on $H^\ast(X)$ then the $E_2$-page can be identified with 
$$H^\ast(BG)\otimes H^\ast(X)$$
*as algebras*. By a classical result of Evens, the mod 2 cohomology algebra of a finite group is finitely generated. Since the tensor product of finitely generated algebras is again finitely generated, so is this $E_2$-page, <strike>and hence so is the equivariant cohomology algebra.</strike> **(see the comments made by Algori and Ralph below.)**

However, in general the coefficients in the $E_2$-page are twisted by the action of $G$ on $H^\ast(X)$ (which in my case happens to be non-trivial), and so I can't see how the argument would go.

At the other extreme, if $G$ acts freely on $X$ then we are basically asking if there is a finite covering space $X\to Y$ such that $H^\ast(X)$ is finitely generated as an algebra but $H^\ast(Y)$ is not. Such a beast would give a counter-example.

(I'm also rather sure that if the answer to my question was yes, Quillen would have told us so!)

Comment: Mark -- re "and hence so is the equivariant cohomology algebra": $E_3$ is the quotient of a subalgebra of $E_2$; now, a subalgebra of a finitely generated algebra is not necessarily finitely generated, so I think an extra argument is needed here.

Comment: $E_2$ is always a finitely generated algebra over $k = \mathbb{F}_2$: By Noether normalization $H^\ast(X)$ is a finitely generated module over a polynomial ring $k[x_1,...x_n]$ and wlog we may assume that the $x_i$ have the same degree. By Dickson invariants, $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a finitely generated module over the $k$-polynomial ring $R := k[x_1,...,x_n]^G$. Thus $H^\ast(X)$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. Now by Evens' theorem $H^\ast(BG;R)$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra and $E_2=H^\ast(BG;H^\ast(X))$ is a finitely generated $H^\ast(BG;R)$-module.

Comment: ... Summarizing, $E_2$ is a finitely generated module over a finitely generated $k$-algebra. In particular, $E_2$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra. --- But as pointed out by algori (and can be seen in Evens' original proof) this doesn't suffice to show finite generation. 

Comment: @Ralph: Is $E_2$ a finitely generated $H^\ast(BG)$-module? If it were, I think this would answer the question as the ring $H^\ast(BG)$ is commutative and Noetherian, and so subquotients of f.g. modules are f.g.

Comment: Mark, $E_2$ is (in general) not finitely generated as $H^\ast(BG;k)$-module. Just take $X=B(\mathbb{Z}/2)^n$ with trivial operation of $G := \mathbb{Z}/2$. Then $E_2=k[x_1,...,x_n,y]$ and $H^\ast(BG)=k[y]$. --- What can be said (notation from my first comment): We have $R=k[y_1,...y_n]$ where $y_i$ are the Dickson invaiants in the $x_i$. By universal coefficients, $H^\ast(BG;R) = H^\ast(BG;k) \otimes R = H^\ast(BG;k) \otimes k[y_1,...,y_n]$ has a nice structure.  Moreover: $R \le H^\ast(X)^G= E_2^{0,\ast}$ and $d_2(y_i^2) = 2y_id_2(y_i) = 0$ what generalizes to $d_r(y_i^{2^r})=0$. 

Comment: ... If one would (!) know that this process stops, $E_2$ would be a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring $S:= H^\ast(BG) \otimes k[y_1^m,...,y_n^m]$ constisting of cocycles. Then $E_3$ is again a Noetherian module over $S$, etc. and the usual method would work. 

Comment: Thanks for your help! In my applications, $G=S_r$ the symmetric group on $r$ letters, acting on the $r$-fold cartesian product $X = Y^{(r)}$ of a space $Y$ with $H^\ast(Y)$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra. I know the mod $2$ cohomology of symmetric groups is a bit messy, but maybe the statement could be true in this case?


Comment: In this case $H_G^\ast(X;k)$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra: By a theorem of Nakaoka, $H^\ast(EG \times_G Y^r;k) \cong H^\ast(BG;H^\ast(Y;k)^{\otimes r})$ as $k$-algebras and the latter is isomophic to $H^\ast(BG;H^\ast(X;k))$ which is just the $E_2$-term of the spectral sequence discussed above. From the considerations in my first comment now the desired result follows. --- You can find Nakaoka's theorem in http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.5017, Theorem 2.1. Note: $X^{\otimes \Omega}$ in that theorem is a typo, it should be $X^\Omega$ as is clear from context or from the proof. 

Comment: @Ralph: I forgot to say, thanks for all your help.